# How can you exclude items in responsive design? [Bootstrap]

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

the answer might have already be somewhere, but chances are, that I might have overlooked it since I'm a 100% new to this (coding) and understand basically half of what I read :)

I'm currently making a website in Bootstrap, and I would like to exclude some elements in responsive mode/design.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that? Is there a specific line of (html?) code that I have to put before the elements that I wish to hide on say view on a phone?

Google hasn't been very useful.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish? Do you want f.e. some image/div that doesn't resize? Or do you want something that f.e. stays in 1 spot for ever? I don't really understand your scenario :)

Comment: Define "Exclude".  Do you mean *do not show* at a certain size? Then use the utility classes such as `visible-xs`, `hidden-xs`, etc.  This is all covered in the bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the **utility classes** of Bootstrap 3 in the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Bootstrap includes utility classes to toggle content across viewport breakpoints. E.g. `.hidden-lg`, which when applied to a HTML element `<div class="hidden-lg"></div>`, hides the element on viewports bigger than 1200px (by default).

Comment: Dear Pivemi, thank you! I must have read this thing a 100 times now, stupid of me to miss it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thnx guys, I have found it :) Totally screwed up responsive by giving my container a fixed width, but I think I can figure that out!

Thnx a lot!